# Sending variables inside the function in laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, function-parameter

Is it possible to get the value of the `$string` which is stored outside the function `(For Mail)`

Here i tried.

```
$string = str_random(5);     

Mail::send([], [], function($message,$string)
    {
        $user = MailTemplate::find(1);
        $mail_body = $user->MailContent;
        $mail_body = str_replace("{password}", $string, $mail_body);
        $message->setBody($mail_body, 'text/html');
        $message->to(Session::get('sess_mail'));
        $message->subject('Password Details - Ma$na Taxi');
    });
```

But it shows error

```
Missing argument 2 for LoginController::{closure}()
```

How can i pass the value of $string inside the mail function like

```
Mail::send([], [], function($message,$string)
```

So it should be accessible at `$mail_body = str_replace("{password}", $string, $mail_body);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to the static method `Mail::send()` needs to match the signature specified here - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail#basic-usage

```
$string = str_random(5);     

Mail::send('name-of-view-used-for-email',
     array('foo' => $string), function($message) use ($string)
    {
        $user = MailTemplate::find(1);
        $mail_body = $user->MailContent;
        $mail_body = str_replace("{password}", $string, $mail_body);
        $message->setBody($mail_body, 'text/html');
        $message->to(Session::get('sess_mail'));
        $message->subject('Password Details - Ma$na Taxi');
    });
```

> How can i pass the value of $string inside the mail function like so
>   it should be accessible at $mail_body = str_replace("{password}",
>   $string, $mail_body);

You have a scope issue - in order to get be pass $string you need to use `use ($string)` before your function call.
As Ive shown in the updated code.

Comment: Thanks, If i need to use $string1, $string2 then i should do `array('foo' => $string, 'foo1' => $string1, 'foo2' => $string2), function($message) use ($string,$string1, $string2 )` Like this right ?

Comment: (assuming you are using blade for the email view ) what you pass in the array can be accessed in `email.blade.php` as  `{{ $foo }} {{ $foo1}} `

Comment: `use ($string,$string1, $string2 )` would only be necessary if you wanted to access those variables inside your function `Mail::send(.... function () { $string,$string1, $string2 }) `